# Why Kivy ScrollView children of child are not scrollable?

Tags: python, kivy, scrollview

This is a part of a **python-script running kivy**:

```
class someclass(Widget):
# code
# code
Clock.schedule_interval(self.timeandlog, 0.1)
self.x = 20
def timeandlog(self,dt):
    if condition == True: # 
       self.ids.pofchild.add_widget(Label(text=logmsg, pos = (10, self.x)))
       self.x = self.x + 10   ### just playing with position 
       condition = False
```

kv file:

```
<someclass>

    #somelabels and buttons:

    ScrollView:
        do_scroll_x: False
        do_scroll_y: True
        pos: root.width*0.3, root.height*0.7
        size: root.width*0.8, root.height*0.7 
        Widget:
            cols: 1 
            spacing: 10
            id: pofchild
```

Now I know the `ScrollView` accepts one `Widget` so I added just one with an `id: pofchild` then I added labels inside it with `self.ids.pofchild.add_widget(Label()` and changing every new label's `pos` with  `pos=(20, self.x)` but the labels are not scrollable and only fill the widget height then stop appearing. What are right attributions so they will be scrollable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, when you want a `Widget` to contain other `Widgets`, you should use a `Layout` `Widget`. A simple `Widget` does not honor `size_hint` or `pos_hint`, so the children of a simple `Widget` often end up with the default size of (100,100) and the default position of (0,0).

So, a good start is to change:

```
class someclass(Widget):
```

to something like:

```
class Someclass(FloatLayout):
```

Note that the class name starts with a capital letter. Although it does not cause any difficulties in your example, it can produce errors when you use `kv` and your classname starts with lower case.

Similarly, the child of the `ScrollView` is also normally a `Layout`. A possibility is `GridLayout`, like this:

```
    GridLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        cols: 1 
        spacing: 10
        id: pofchild
```

Keys attributes here are the `size_hint_y: None` and `height: self.minimum_height`. They allow the `GridLayout` to grow as more children are added, and its height will be calculated as the minimum height needed to contain the children.

Then, you can add children like this:

```
self.ids.pofchild.add_widget(Label(text=logmsg, pos=(10, self.x), size_hint_y=None, height=50))
```

Since we are expecting the `GridLayout` to calculate its minimum height, we must provide an explicit `height` for its children, thus the `size_hint_y=None, height=50`.